# Is there an easy way to locally change font size/type/weight?

Tags: r, quarto

I am experimenting with R Quarto to create PowerPoint presentations. I have worked out how to use a PowerPoint template (Quarto is particular about this; I find that creating a blank Quarto PowerPoint file and editing it to your requirements is the easiest way).

The disadvantage of the template is that I now am limited to the available styles. As you know, in a PPT presentation one routinely deviates from the default styles to e.g. fit more text on a page.

I cannot find a good reference on how to implement local styles that are different from the template. I had hoped that Quarto allows e.g. execution options in curly brackets or some css type style definitions to do this.
Below is how I would envision such a thing (I know, it's simplistic).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
---
title: "MY PRESENTATION"
subtitle: "this is a subtitle"
format: 
  pptx:
    reference-doc: my_template.pptx
author: me 
date: today
date-format: long
footer: "confidential"
---

## First slide

-   first content
-   second content {style = "font:'Arial';font-size:14px"}
```

Comment: I'm guessing (but am not sure) that the translation to PPTX is done via pandoc and hence that you have  very little control/flexibility beyond what you can do by modifying the template, e.g. see https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/10.1-structuring-the-slide-show.html  ... maybe the [officer package](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/) could help ... (I have no idea whether pandoc translates HTML-level info into PPTX or not ... https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/presentations/pptx.html)

Comment: Thanks Ben! I have worked extensively with the officer package and it is a fantastic package! I did realise that Quarto is based on Pandoc and I have been looking through pandoc documentation for ways to do this. 

I was hoping that Quarto offers tools to allow for the real world flexibility that one needs when creating presentations.